# Creating Folder in Application Support if not Exists

Tags: swift, macos, nsfilemanager

I'm trying to create a folder in Application Support Directory.

```
let path = FileManager.default.urls(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
let fileurl =  path.appendingPathComponent("my folder")
do {
try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath:String(describing: fileurl), withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
} catch {
 print(error)
}
```

But no folder is created.What I'm I doing wrong?

Comment: My comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46695044/decrypted-string-always-returning-null#comment80338247_46695044 to your previous question applies here as well: Never use `String(describing:)` !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error occurs because you are passing the string representation of an URL which includes the `file://` scheme but `createDirectory(atPath` expects a `path` without the `file://` scheme.

The solution is so easy: (Always) use the URL related API of `FileManager`

```
try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: fileurl, withIntermediateDirectories: true)
```

Please consider a more meaningful variable naming

- `path` is actually `url`
- `fileurl` is actually `folderurl`

Comment: Thanks ... Does this method check if the Directory already exists ?

Comment: No, you have to check this.

Comment: @techno No need to check if exists. It will only create the directory if it doesn't exist.